# Некорректно работает Бинарный Поиск в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Я не могу понять, почему же, при попытке вывести значения из массива, Я получил: -1. Это правило не работает на все значения в массиве, но исключения всё таки есть. И это: Банан, Киви, Клубника. Данные 3 значения - выдают то, что от них ожидалось. А остальные значения - нет.
Чтобы не возникало вопросов, предоставлю Вам код:

```js
var array = ["Груша", "Яблоко", "Абрикос", "Банан", "Апельсин", "Киви", "Клубника"];

function binarySearch(arr, value) {
  var first = 0;
  var last = arr.length - 1;
  var middle;

  while (first <= last) {
    middle = Math.floor((first + last) / 2);
    if (arr[middle] === value) {
      return arr[middle];
    } else if (arr[middle] > value) {
      last = middle - 1;
    } else {
      first = middle + 1;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
var wasItFound = binarySearch(array, "Груша");
console.log(wasItFound);
```

Что же мне делать, чтобы исправить это? Помогите пожалуйста, уже долго сижу над этой задачкой.

Comment: Бинарный поиск ищет по отсортированному массиву.

Answer (score 3):

Бинарный поиск производит поиск по отсортированному массиву. Это одно из ключевых условий. Поиск происходит путем сравнения искомого элемента с центральным, если это искомый элемент, то поиск прекращается, если нет, то отсекается та половина, в которой элемента быть не может. Из описания следует что нет возможности произвести поиск подобного рода по неотсортированному  массиву. [Более полное](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA)